# Is it possible to remove hidden iCloud folders in Mobile Documents?

Tags: macos, icloud, finder

I discovered that inside the `~/Library/Mobile Documents` folder is a trove of directories for what seems like every app that has been granted access to a user's iCloud drive. Some of these folders can be accessed via `Manage Storage` and selecting the associated app. However, there are folders from apps that have been uninstalled. Is there a way to remove these folders? I've tried using Terminal, but it acts like the folder doesn't exist.

[image: iCloud Drive App Folders]

Comment: AFAIK, they are the local copies of what is there in iCloud. You can even find locations to your iCloud Drive documents there. You should delete the related items in iCloud preferences.

Comment: You can't delete the related items in iCloud preferences if the app is no longer installed since there is no reference to it.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/298834/313842 See the comments, it works for some apps. also, on iOS, I just saw apps like Agenda which I have uninstalled, but still have data in iCloud. See. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/335301/whats-included-in-library-mobile-documents-folder-and-is-there-anyway-to-safely?rq=1 too