# Remove faded folders in iCloud Drive

Tags: icloud, finder

Some apps create their own folder in the iCloud Drive. Because I want to see everything all the time I enabled *show hidden files* (like [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/258733/how-to-show-hidden-files-on-mac-without-terminal)).

So this is how my iCloud Drive folder looks like:
[image: my iCloud Drive]

### Problem

I do not need the faded out folders "PrinterPro", "Sprit-Rechner", "PDF Expert", "PRINT" and "Trails" and **I can't delete** them. They will just come back.

### Solution Attempt

The left side of the picture shows my iCloud Drive settings where you can enable or disable some folders, but the faded out do not show up there. I also tried to reinstall the apps but I can't find any option for iCloud folders.

Comment: Are these apps installed on other devices connected to your iCloud account such as an iPhone or iPad?

Comment: Did you consider turning hidden files back on? Apple hides some files for a reason *the are only of utility to the OS or an App.* There is nothing there that you can meaningfully interact with, so why annoy yourself with folders and files that are automatically created/re-created that you can't do anything about?

Comment: @JBis No they are not. I deleted them years ago.

Comment: @SteveChambers There are some places where I need to see the hidden files. Especially on remote directories.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to delete the hidden folders that existed in the root of my iCloud Drive from iOS and macOS that apps I'd previously deleted from my devices.

I'm using macOS Catalina version 10.15.2 but this may work on earlier versions of macOS.

1. Open Terminal.app and type this but do not press return yet:

   ```
   rm -rf
   ```
2. Make sure there is a space after the "f" at the end of the command
3. In Finder, open the iCloud Drive folder and change it to List view (command+2) so you can easily see all of the hidden folders.
4. Select all of the folders you want to delete, then drag them in to the Terminal window. It will automatically add the path of the folders to the command, separated by spaces.

   So the command would look something like this:

   ```
   rm -rf /Users/username/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~Automator/Documents /Users/username/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~ScriptEditor2/Documents /Users/username/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~TextEdit/Documents /Users/username/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~QuickTimePlayerX/Documents /Users/username/Library/Mobile\ Documents/6LVTQB9699~com~seriflabs~affinitydesigner/Documents /Users/username/Library/Mobile\ Documents/iCloud~net~doo~scanbot~vpp/Documents /Users/username/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~Numbers/Documents /Users/username/Library/Mobile\ Documents/F6266T9T75~com~apple~iMovie/Documents /Users/username/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~Keynote/Documents /Users/username/Library/Mobile\ Documents/WUGMZZ5K46~com~bohemiancoding~sketch/Documents /Users/username/Library/Mobile\ Documents/iCloud~com~readdle~Scanner~PDF/Documents  /Users/username/Library/Mobile\ Documents/iCloud~is~workflow~my~workflows/Documents /Users/username/Library/Mobile\ Documents/F3LWYJ7GM7~com~apple~garageband10/Documents /Users/username/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~Preview/Documents
   ```
5. Press return. It may ask you for your computer password.
6. After running the command, nothing will happen in the iCloud Drive window.

   The only two things I observed at this point that were different from before were:

   a. When clicking on of one of the folders, the Finder Path Bar will show iCloud > and the folder's icon, but will not show the folder name

   b. Dragging the folder to Terminal again does nothing - it does not generate the text path like before.
7. Restart your Mac
8. Return to iCloud Drive in Finder and the hidden folders should be gone.

Comment: After removing the folders, the fans on my laptop started to spin up and iCloud began syncing all my documents. After a restart the hidden folder has not reappeared. Thank you!

Comment: worked for me :)

Comment: Buy why wait 15 minuts?

Comment: @jiamo I remember when I'd first discovered this solution it took about 15 minutes for it to work but I've tested these steps again just now on a new computer running macOS Big Sur 11.1 and I did not need to wait 15 minutes, so I've updated the answer.

Comment: Doesn't work on macOS 11.5.2 (20G95).

Comment: Works perfectly, macOS 12.2 (21D49). Thank you!

Comment: No need to do a full Mac restart on Step 7. Relaunch Finder with Command + Option + Esc