# Delete iCloud hidden folders of uninstalled apps

Tags: icloud

I want to remove these folders but I can´t just turn of the sync function in the settings. It´s not there. At least not for those apps. I´ve also tried to delete the session files in /Users/myname/Library/Application Support/CloudDocs.

I just can´t get rid of these folders which is annoying.

Comment: Looks same as https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/328499/remove-faded-folders-in-icloud-drive Does the solution work for you? If not, you might like to update the question to indicate that you have tried that solution.

Comment: I don´t know what I did but now I can´t see any hidden folders anymore. But the Desktop and documents folder are still in iCloud even I have turned off syncing.